# Balana Request matching Error with new AttributeDesignator

Tags: xacml3, pdp, balana

I have two Policies stores. One is Simple Policy Store (SPS) and other is Administrative Policy Store (APS). Simple access request against access policies is working properly.. However, when I evaluate administrative request against following policy (APS) ....(i have shown one component policy only );

```
<Target>
<AnyOf>
<AllOf>
<Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">shibli</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:delegate" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
</Match>
</AllOf>
</AnyOf>
</Target>
```

then this will generate following error ;

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"><Result><Decision>Indeterminate</Decision><Status><StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:missing-attribute"/><StatusMessage>Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute</StatusMessage><StatusDetail>
<MissingAttributeDetail AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" ></MissingAttributeDetail>
</StatusDetail></Status></Result></Response>.
```

**UPDATE:**
And here is my request ;

```
"<Attributes Category=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:delegate\">\n"+
            "<Attribute AttributeId=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id\" IncludeInResult=\"false\">\n"+
            "<AttributeValue DataType=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string\">"+issuer+"</AttributeValue>\n"+
            "</Attribute>\n"+
            "</Attributes>\n"+
```

Any one can guide me !

Thanks in advance

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The error is normal. Your policy expects the following attribute:

- attribute id: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id
- datatype: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
- category: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:**delegate**

The flag `MustBePresent` is set to `true` meaning that if the attribute is missing (i.e. there are no values), then `Indeterminate` will be returned.

The response to your request contains:

- attribute id: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id
- datatype: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
- category: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:**access-subject**

Notice how the category values are different. What this means is that you are not actually evaluating the policy you showed us in the first snippet, or if you are, then it also contains a section with a required subject id attribute.

To proceed, it would be good for you to show the request you sent. Also, make sure you have the right policy deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by placing Administrative Policies and Access Policies into two different folders. I think Balana can't read different type of policies which are in same folders.